# Networking with Direct Attached twinax cables

Tags: networking

This shows my lack of experience I think. But, I added 2 port 10G SFP+ cards to 3 dell R610 servers running windows 2012. Then I connected them together using direct attached twinax cables. At the moment I cannot ping any of the non direct attached ports. How do I configure it so that I have a network between the 3 servers without the use of a switch? Or is it possible?

Comment: How are IP settings configured on the servers? What exactly are you trying to ping?

Comment: Here's a link to a diagram. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/331y7046fpi15i6/Untitled-3.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: That's the most insane way to configure a network I've ever seen... and I've seen many. It just can't possibly work.

Comment: Ha ha, ok. Any suggestion as to how I can make this work? Any suggested hardware?

Comment: Get a switch. You just can't connect three servers without one, unless you want to use three distinct IP subnets and a lot of headache medications.

Comment: Any particular model/brand? I couldn't find one online that works with SFP+ DAC twinax.